# Polars LazyFrame streaming directly to (partitioned) Parquet without collecting

Tags: python, python-polars

I am reading some data from AWS S3 with `polars.scan_pyarrow_dataset`. When I am finished with my data processing, I would like to write the results back to cloud storage, in partitioned Parquet files. However, I'd like to avoid collecting all results in memory. I believe this should be possible with the Parquet format because of its support for a row groups, as well as the ability to split the data into physically separate files.

I don't see any support for this in the Polars LazyFrame API. I see that `collect` has `streaming=True`, but that still looks like it collects the final result in memory.

Is there some way to achieve this that I am not seeing?

Comment: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet.html#polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet

Answer (score 3):

polars doesn't yet have a partitioned writer. Its streaming engine also doesn't support `pyarrow_datasets`.

It does support S3 files directly though so unless you're working under some special case, you can skip the scan_pyarrow_dataset and use the built in cloud reader.

See the [scan_parquet](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_parquet.html#polars-scan-parquet) docs. If you give it the appropriate `storage_options` then you can read a hive partition directly. One difference is that, in contrast, to this syntax `ds.dataset("/path/to/root_directory", ...)` you'd do `pl.scan_parquet("s3://path/to/root_directory/**/**/*.parquet", ...)`

Given a LazyFrame that was generated that way, you will have streaming support. `sink_parquet` doesn't have cloud support though. You could use `sink_parquet` to a local file and then use the pyarrow dataset writer to partition it to its ultimate destination

For example:

```
df=pl.scan_parquet("s3://path/to/root_directory/**/**/*.parquet", 
                   storage_options=your_options_dict)

df = df#all your data processing

df.sink_parquet("some_local.parquet")

sourcepq=ds.dataset("some_local.parquet").scanner()

s3_filesystem = s3fs(...)

ds.write_dataset(sourcepq, 
             "/destination/path/on/s3", 
             filesystem=s3_filesystem,
             partitioning = ['col1','col2'], 
             partitioning_flavor='hive')
```